# Copy text from a basic "Text Box" and paste it into a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

I'm trying to access the text inside "Text Box 1", copy it and then paste it into a range beginning at `A37`.

**UPDATE**: the text boxes in question are simple text boxes that have been inserted using: Insert Tab > Text box button.

Below is a shambles of things I'm experimenting with. I can't seem to find the way to get at the text and copy it. Any ideas?

```
Sub textbox()

    Dim txBox As Shape
    Set txBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Text Box 1")
    'shpTextBox.selStart = 0
    'shpTextBox.SelLength = Len(shpTextBox.Text)

    txBox.Select
    txBox.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    Range("A37").Value = shpTextBox.Value    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works when I try it:

```
Dim txBox As Shape
Set txBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Text Box 1")

Range("A37").Value = txBox.TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

Comment: These text boxes already exist in the sheets I'm updating. They are simple text boxes inserted using the Insert Tab > Text box button. I think this may be why I'm running into the problems.

Comment: @RocketGoal: see updated answer